# Query DB2 without using Openquery

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, db2

Is there a way to query a DB2 Linked Server without using Openquery?  IE, is it possible to query DB2 through a linked server by doing something like the following?

```
select *
from [db2_linked_server].[database].[tablename]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your linked server provider supports it, you should be able to use a 4-part name (your example only used 3-parts)

I'm referencing [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions-Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql).

```
server_name .[database_name].[schema_name].object_name
```

WHERE

> **server_name** Specifies a linked server name or remote server name.
>
> **database_name** Specifies the name of a SQL Server database when the
>   object resides in a local instance of SQL Server. When the object is
>   in a linked server, database_name specifies an OLE DB catalog.
>
> **schema_name** Specifies the name of the schema that contains the object
>   if the object is in a SQL Server database. When the object is in a
>   linked server, schema_name specifies an OLE DB schema name.
>
> **object_name** Refers to the name of the object.

Comment: However, understand that accessing a DB2 linked server via 4-part name means that MS SQL Server pulls back the entire table and does any `WHERE` clause locally.  Whereas with `OPENQUERY`, the entire statement is sent to the remote server and the `WHERE` clause is done on the remote server.